# When importing Material Top Tabs from React Navigation, I get: "requireNativeComponent: "RNCViewPager" was not found in the UIManager."

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I tried adding @react-native-community/viewpager but had no success. Is there some way to disable the view pager for the top tab navigator?

Comment: How did you solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

After adding the @react-native-community/viewpager library with npm, you should close the android studio emulator and launch the app again, i did that and worked just fine (reload the NPM bundle too).

Answer (score 0):

please try to link npm and rebuild app and run.

```
react-native link <"your tab/view pager npm">
```

Now rebuild project and run.